# Was a copy of Bobadilla's report on Christopher Columbus really found in a Spanish archive in 2006?

Tags: spain, sources, new-world, christopher-columbus, caribbean

As claimed in [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2006/aug/07/books.spain)

A transcription of the document is apparently available on JSTOR [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt6wptvz), the section "Pesquisa Del Comendador Francisco de Bobadilla".

I cannot read Spanish and otherwise lack expertise to form any opinion on whether the document seems genuine.

Does anyone here know if the document is genuine? Or can you form any kind of impression or opinion based on the JSTOR source?

Comment: I haven't found much in English beyond the guardian article (in particular no translation), and the Spanish-language book is not (yet) widely cited. The guardian article only quotes the author of the book iirc. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary corroboration.

Comment: This hardly seem like an "extraordinary claim" to me, since it comports well with existing knowledge. The work by Consuelo Varela and Isabel Aguirre appears to be fairly widely cited in [relevant literature](https://scholar.google.com.tw/scholar?cites=9025206554042940316) (i.e. not newspaper) too.

Comment: I think any claim of "legendary document stumbled upon in archive"  require.s corroboration. 21 citations for such a recent book perhaps ain't bad, but none of those publications themselves have many citations.

Comment: Would like to see the claim confirmed independently of Varela

Comment: The archivist Isabel Aguirre transcribed the actual report, so this "claim" is prima facie corroborated. And how is it legendary? The claim is "report filed by an agent of the Spanish government was discovered in the archives of the Spanish government". A relatively routine event, to be honest.

Comment: I meant it is a pre/early modern document whose existence is described in historical sources, but was lost, and one that provides unusually detailed information on a controversial historical figure.

Comment: I agree it is not an implausible find, but the lack of corroboration 10 years later concerning. Would not view the transcriber as "independent" of Varela. But perhaps you made more headway in understanding the Spanish source?

Comment: No, it really isn't. The original document is presumably still at the archive, and no one is going to go out of their way to "corroborate" something not in dispute. Actually, the idea that a head of department at the Archivo General de Simancas (an official institution) would conspire with a respected scholar and a major publishing house to forge a historical document (that's neither legendary nor particularly unusual despite exaggerations to the contrary) is simply incredible. Especially in the absence of any evidence.

Comment: That is a fair argument, although I'm not sure why you dismiss the significance of the document as it seems like an excellent contemporary source. Was not aware of the position of the transcriber. The Spanish-language review of the book linked from the JSTOR page is further corroborative. Overall, it looks legit, but I would still prefer to see greater confirmation before I would feel comfortable referring people to the guardian article as fact.

Comment: I agree with other commenters that as far as believability, the identity of the writer involved may reveal more than the text itself.